# jQuery mouse click event handler

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

I want to make some keyboard shortcuts where I want to trigger the same thing that happens when a span-box is clicked. It needs to work in IE7.  How could I do this?  Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<li id="detail">
  <a href="#" onClick="access(this);">
    <span>Detailed Report</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li id="product">
  <a href="#" onClick="access(this);">
    <span>Product Area Report</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

**JQUERY**

```
(document).keypress(function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).is('input, textarea')) {
        var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
        switch ( code ) {
            case 13: //enter
                getTable();
                return false;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi there! There was an edit on your post and I think it might have changed the underlying question.. Are you satisfied with the edit?

Comment: @Lix I'm pretty sure the edit didn't change any of the meaning of the post - in the original version, the OP indicated that he wanted to trigger something when the "span-box" was clicked.

Comment: @ape - actually the original version says that they want `"to trigger a click on span-box"`. From that I understand that the OP wants to **generate** a click event and not to **handle** it. But I could be wrong - hence the comment :P

Comment: As I understand it, a keyboard shortcut is supposed to simulate a click on an element.

Comment: Good point.  Edited back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML:

```
<li id="detail">
  <a href="#" class="detail-report">
    <span>Detailed Report</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li id="product">
  <a href="#" class="product-report">
    <span>Product Area Report</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

The jQuery:

```
  $(function(){

        $(".detail-report").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          /*trigger the other thing here*/
          alert("clicked on the detail report");
          myevent(); //declare a function somewhere in the scope of your js and call it here :)
        });

        $(".product-report").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          /*trigger the other thing here*/
          alert("clicked on the product report"); 
        });
    });
```

My [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/FuM7N/)

You can also blend in this idea with the keydown function like this...

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch(e.KeyCode) {
//you just gotta know your key codes and what numbers they are associated to!
case 68: //when you press the (d) key trigger something...
  alert('i used my keyboard to press the d key.')
 myevent(); //you can call that same function that you created earlier, and place it here.
break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Are there a way to avoid making a need click function for each span. Link index or something.

Comment: You can do something this like this  - $(".product-report, .detail-report").click(function(e) {...}

Comment: or if there no unique actions between the 2 span locations, create one class name and use it on both elements, and apply it to one click action, like $(".reports").click(function(e) {...}

Answer (score 3):

> I understood from the original version of your question that you were looking or a way to *generate* a click event.

There are two very similar ways to trigger a click on an element with jQuery.

1. `$(element).click()`
2. `$(element).trigger('click')`

The same `trigger()` function can also be used for other types of events. For example,

```
$(element).trigger('submit'); // for a form element
$(element).trigger('dblclick'); // for a double click event
```

#### References - [`trigger()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Okay, that worked, but I need to add class for each SPAN-tag and add a click function to it.